# Easiest/affordable way to monitor what's using power in your home?

Tags: electrical, saving-money

My electric bill seems to be unusually high.

I'm trying to figure out if there is an issue somewhere (faulty wiring, someone stealing power etc) or if one of my devices is a power hog.

Does anyone know of an easier way to monitor the use of their electric?

Answer (score 1):

I use a "Kill-A-Watt" like this one [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt) for plug-in devices.

For hard-wired device you would have to connect an attachment plug to the device and plug it in to the Kill-A-Watt.

You could also take amprobe and voltage readings of your equipment to verify it's power draw.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Do you recommend any brand of Kill-a-Watt?

Comment: Kill-a-watt is a brand.  Their bottom model is about $20US. They make better ones, as do others.

Comment: A good start would be to audit all of the equipment and lighting in your house and make a list of their power requirements. Then see if there is anything you want to eliminate or update.